# Generate WORKFLOW in plSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

i try to generate a workflow with recusive functions in plSQL but i don't get what i want.

i got this table TABLETEST :

```
GROUPE  STATUS  STATUSNEW
A          A1      A2
A          A1      A3
A          A3      A1
A          A2      A4
A          A3      A5
A          A5      A6
A          A6      A2
A          A2      A10
B          A2      A3
B          A2      A3
B          A2      A10

  CREATE TABLE "TABLETEST" 
   (    "GROUPE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "STATUSNEW" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "XXXXXXXX" ;

  INSERT INTO TABLETEST ( GROUPE , STATUS , STATUSNEW ) VALUES('A','A1','A2');
  INSERT INTO TABLETEST ( GROUPE , STATUS , STATUSNEW ) VALUES('A','A1','A3');
  INSERT INTO TABLETEST ( GROUPE , STATUS , STATUSNEW ) VALUES('A','A3','A1');
  INSERT INTO TABLETEST ( GROUPE , STATUS , STATUSNEW ) VALUES('A','A2','A4');
  INSERT INTO TABLETEST ( GROUPE , STATUS , STATUSNEW ) VALUES('A','A3','A5');
  INSERT INTO TABLETEST ( GROUPE , STATUS , STATUSNEW ) VALUES('A','A5','A6');
  INSERT INTO TABLETEST ( GROUPE , STATUS , STATUSNEW ) VALUES('A','A6','A2');
  INSERT INTO TABLETEST ( GROUPE , STATUS , STATUSNEW ) VALUES('A','A2','A10');
  INSERT INTO TABLETEST ( GROUPE , STATUS , STATUSNEW ) VALUES('B','A2','A3');
  INSERT INTO TABLETEST ( GROUPE , STATUS , STATUSNEW ) VALUES('B','A2','A3');
  INSERT INTO TABLETEST ( GROUPE , STATUS , STATUSNEW ) VALUES('B','A2','A10');
```

I tried this :

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT STATUS   , STATUSNEW,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT STATUS  || SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(STATUSNEW,'//') p
FROM ( SELECT * FROM TABLETEST WHERE GROUPE= 'A' )
WHERE 
CONNECT_BY_ROOT STATUS  != STATUSNEW
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE STATUS   = PRIOR STATUSNEW
ORDER SIBLINGS BY STATUS    ,  STATUSNEW, P;
```

But i don't get what i want :

My goal is generate the full workflow for 1 group ( First A , Then b ... )

Actually, i got this :

```
A1  A2  A1//A2
A1  A10 A1//A2//A10
A1  A4  A1//A2//A4
A1  A3  A1//A3
A1  A2  A1//A3//A1//A2
A1  A10 A1//A3//A1//A2//A10
A1  A4  A1//A3//A1//A2//A4
A1  A5  A1//A3//A5
A1  A6  A1//A3//A5//A6
```

I want my workflow like a tree , for GROUP A :

```
A1 <-----------|
--->A2 <-------|---|   
--->--->A4     |   |
--->--->A10    |   |
--->A3         |   |
--->--->--->--->   |
--->--->A5         |
--->--->--->A6     |
--->--->--->--->--->
...
```

( i want my workflow like a state machine )

Any clue ?

Thanks a lot !